# Apache Unable to Write to File

Tags: php, file, permissions, fedora

I am using Fedora 24 on VirtualBox to host a small PHP web app. I am trying to append text into a file that is in the same local directory as the PHP file (/var/www/html/). No matter what kind of permissions or ownerships I try to set onto the directory (html/) or the file I constantly get "Permission denied in /var/www/html/pdf.php on line 21" errors.

Is there any configuration settings in my php.ini file that I need to enable to allow editing of files? I've even tried setting the directory and file to chmod 777 just to see if it would give me access but even that is being rejected.

EDIT: I have also tried creating directories and files in other locations with the same results. I tried to have Apache run the mkdir and touch commands with the same results.

EDIT 2: At the request of the comment left to my initial question. Here is the ownership information for the target directory:
ls -l /var/www/html/
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache apache 4096 Nov 23 21:28 docs

The ownership information for the file:
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 apache apache 1381 Nov 28 17:47 pdf.php

Comment: Alrighty, can you show who owns the file that's trying to write AND the owner of the location that you want to write to (*usually done through: `ls -l /var/www/html`*) and add it to your question :) 9/10 it's ownership issues. Also, which user owns/runs your apache instance? As that user needs to own the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning to www-data:nobody

`chown -R www-data:nobody *`, check apache group on your httpd.conf.

Verify /var/html perms to 775 at least.

Comment: This worked, but I rebuilt my app on an Ubuntu platform instead of Fedora. After messing with the Fedora permissions so much my virtual machine image would no longer boot properly. So I rebuilt my LAMP stack on an Ubuntu system and set the permissions described here and it is now writing properly. I should note that the 'nobody' user group did not exist but the 'www-data' user did. It belonged to a user group of the same name so the command I used was chown -R www-data:www-data * in the directory containing my PHP files and the file I was writing to.

Answer (score 0):

Spent a lot of time looking for this answer but it's all in bits and pieces and no one every posts a solution (well most of the time) so here is my solution and it's used on various web control panels as well.

install and use MOD_RUID2

Install PHP with CLI (this is standard on newer versions)

In your HTTPD.CONF file in the virtual hosts, you'll add the following, replacing username with the user's login name, and usergroup with the user's group (These are usually the same)

```
<IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
    SuexecUserGroup username usergroup
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
    RMode config
    RUidGid username usergroup
    RGroups @none
</IfModule>
```

**An example of a Virtual host conf is:**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  DocumentRoot "/home/imtheuser/public_html"
  ServerName imtheuser.com
  <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
    SuexecUserGroup imtheuser imtheuser
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
    RMode config
    RUidGid imtheuser imtheuser
    RGroups @none
  </IfModule>
  <Directory "/home/imtheuser/public_html">
    allow from all
    Options None
    Require all granted
  </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

This will allow apache/php to write to a directory owned by the user. It's much safer then setting your chmod to 0777.